# Selenium IDE - Error: Permission denied for <http://www.example.com> to get property Location.href

Tags: javascript, selenium, cross-domain

I am using Selenium 1.7.2 on Firefox 11 running on Ubuntu 11.10. Until yesterday, we didn't use the `document.domain` javascript. We needed to add it to our generated HTML and in one of our javascript file.
Now when we run Selenium IDE Test Suite, we get the following error:

```
Error: Permission denied for <http://dev.example.com> to get property Location.href
```

`dev.example.com` is our application server (Glassfish 3.1.2 behind Apache+mod_jk)

If I comment out `document.domain` everything works well (at least in Firefox, because the document.domain is to prevent IE to block PIE.htc script... *sigh* )

I tried adding a user extension script found [here](http://old.nabble.com/Enhancement-request-for-Selenium-for-document.domain-td3613716.html):

```
function setdom(str,doc,dom) {
  doc.domain = dom;
}

Selenium.prototype.doDocumentDomain = function(domain) {
  var lw;
  setdom('ts',frames['testSuiteFrame'].document, domain);
  setdom('tf', getTestFrame().contentWindow.document, domain);
  setdom('my', frames['myiframe'].document, domain);

  lw = LOG.getLogWindow();
  if (lw) {
    setdom('log', lw.document, domain);
    }
  setdom('doc', document, domain);
  }
```

but this looks pretty old and probably not compatible any more. It returns an error at the first call to the `setdom('ts',frames['testSuiteFrame'].document,domain);` line

I am not browsing back and forth between HTTP and HTTPS, I have read many StackOverflow and Google Group related questions, to no result.

I can modify our codes to include `document.domain` only for IE but it is not very clean...

Question: How to make Selenium IDE working without security issue when document.domain is set? Or how can I fix he above user extension to work in Selenium IDE 1.7.2? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to change Selenium javascript to allow me to set the document.domain using this:

In `chrome/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js on line 920 (for version 1.7.2):

```
    //Samit: Fix: open command sometimes fails if current url is chrome and new is not
    windowObject = core.firefox.unwrap(windowObject);
    // -------------- Start My Change ----------------
    updateDomain(windowObject.document);
    // -------------- End My Change ----------------
    if (this._windowClosed(windowObject)) {
        LOG.debug("pollForLoad WINDOW CLOSED (" + marker + ")");
        delete this.pollingForLoad[marker];
        return;
    }
```

Then in user-extensions.js:

```
var validDomain = null;

Selenium.prototype.doDocumentDomain = function(domain) {
  validDomain = domain;
}

function updateDomain(doc) {
  if(validDomain==null) {
    return;
    }
  LOG.info("Current domain: " + doc.domain);
  if(doc.domain != validDomain && (doc.domain+"").indexOf(validDomain)>0 ) {
    doc.domain = validDomain;
    }
  LOG.info("New domain: " + doc.domain);
  }
```

I check prior to setting the new domain that it is a subdomain of the one I want to set. I use it in Selenium IDE:

```
documentDomain | example.com
```

So when it opens dev.example.com and static.example.com, it finds `example.com` in the domain and replace the domain.